# Sharing data between Elastic Beanstalk web and worker tiers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a platform (based on Rails 4/Postgres) running on an auto scaling Elastic Beanstalk web environment. I'm planning on offloading long running tasks (sync with 3rd parties, delivering email etc) to a Worker tier, which appears simple enough to get up and running.

However, I also want to run periodic batch processes. I've looked into using cron.yml and the scheduling seems pretty simple, however the batch process I'm trying to build needs to access the data from the web application to be able to work.

Does anybody have any opinion of the best way of doing this? Either a shared RDS database between web and worker tier, or perhaps a web service that the worker tier can access?

Thanks,
Dan

> Note: I've added an extra question, which more broadly describes my 
>   requirements as it struck me that this might not be the best approach. 
>   [What's the best way to implement this shared batch process with Elastic Beanstalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403429/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-this-shared-batch-process-with-elastic-beanstal)

Comment: I would just access the same Postgres DB that your Rails application is accessing. Concerning the setup of your worker tier: here is a gem I wrote, which should ease the process -> https://github.com/tawan/active-elastic-job

Comment: That looks great, thanks. Is there a preferred way of sharing the database credentials (which are auto generated environment variables) between elastic beanstalk web tier (where the database resides) and the new worker tier?

Comment: You can add the same environment variables to the worker tier. In your AWS console: select worker environment -> Configuration -> Software configuration -> environment properties

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need a full relational database management system (RDBMS), consider using S3 for shared persistent data storage across your instances.

Also consider [Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/):

> SQS is a fast, reliable, scalable, fully managed message queuing
>   service. SQS makes it simple and cost-effective to decouple the
>   components of a cloud application. You can use SQS to transmit any
>   volume of data, at any level of throughput, without losing messages or
>   requiring other services to be always available.